# Celda de datagridview muestra fecha diferente a la tabla de fox prox

Tags: vb.net

Buenas noches una consulta estoy realizando en visual basic 2010 una aplicacion que me extraiga los campos de una tabla de fox porx pero hay un campo de tipo fecha que esta vacia, cuando enlazo al daagridviewesa celda me muestra la fecha 30/12/1899, debería mostrar tambien vacia tal como esta en la tabla de fox prox

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

modulo de clase

```
Public Function Carga_tb_kardex() As DataTable
    datab_tbkardex = New DataTable
    datadapt_tbkardex = New OdbcDataAdapter("select codmod, cargo, apepater, apemater, nombre, monto, f_inicre from kardex order by apepater, apemater, nombre", Conexion)
    datadapt_tbkardex.Fill(datab_tbkardex)
    Conexion.Close()
    Return datab_tbkardex
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    coneccion_data.Conectar_db()
    tabla = coneccion_data.Carga_tb_kardex
    DataGridView1.DataSource = tabla
    utilidades.Deshabilitar_Columnas(Me)
End Sub
```

Comment: Cuando una consulta te devuelve una fecha como NULL, por defecto, la columna de tipo Date o DateTime te pone el MinValue, que en este caso, es 30/12/1899. Para dejar la celda vacia deberias forzar que el valor que te devuelve la consulta es un campo de texto, en caso de que no haya fecha que te devuelva "" y si tiene fecha entonces te devuelva la fecha como texto.

Comment: Ok. gracias por tu aporte, me sairvió tu lógica, lo cambie de esto:  datadapt_tbkardex = New OdbcDataAdapter("select codmod, cargo, apepater, apemater, nombre, nombres, monto, f_inicre from kardex order by apepater, apemater, nombre", Conexion)   a esto;  datadapt_tbkardex = New OdbcDataAdapter("select codmod, cargo, apepater, apemater, nombre, nombres, monto, dtoc(f_inicre) as f_inicre from kardex order by apepater, apemater, nombre", Conexion)